# Get boundaries of open from all assemblies in C#

Tags: c#, forms, desktop, boundary

I'd like to build a function that gives the user the possibility to select a certain window, the whole desktop or the taskbar.
A good example for that should be the "Snipping Tool"s Window Mode.

After the user has selected the window I need some metadata from the selected window. Mainly its assembly-name, form-name and it's boundaries.

Can anyone give me some keywords or examples to give me an idea how to start?

Comment: You should probably reword the title of your question to something like "Get metadata from selected windows." You should also add the target operating system to your question since .NET is cross-platform and target platform is going to affect how you grab the screen and other such concerns. Finally, keep in mind many applications aren't using .NET ("assembly" is purely a .NET concept).

Answer (score 0):

You need Win32 functions for that. And keep in mind, that only small subset of applications are written in .net, so you mainly can't can assembly nam nor form-name. However values like title and bounds are available.

Some of functions what you will need:

- [EnumWindows](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumwindows)
- [GetWindowText](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowtext)
- [GetWindowRect](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowrect)